# 10,000 liquid tether was transferred to my coin base account!

Tags: polygon, coinbase, scam

On march first of 2024 I received a notification that 10,000 liquid tether was transferred into my coin base wallet. The wallet it was transferred from is all 0's. The profile picture says USD and it has the Matic symbol on the bottom right. The network it was sent from was also polygon. It looks like I am able to transfer the funds out of my account if I do choose to, however I will most definitely not touch that money. I have reached out to polygon support about this so I should have answer in a few days. In the meantime if anyone knows what's going on let me know. Most likely a scam.

Comment: Check the address of token contract on the matic/polygon network and the official documentation of the project. Since names could be duplicated by anyone it is very likely it is a scam.

Comment: Hey man! Matic got bag to me and let me know it was a scam. I knew it was one from the jump.... but in the crypto world a mans gotta dream haha